# Why can't we pass a property as argument to Property#unbind() in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, bidirectional

Lets consider two methods of `Property` interface:

```
Property#unbind() 
Property#unbindBidirectional(Property<T> other)
```

As we see, when we want to remove bidirectional binding we can pass the property for which we want to remove this binding.

However, when we remove unidirectional binding we can not pass such property. How to explain it?

Comment: Why do you want to pass an additional property to the `unbind()` call? You already define which property to unbind by calling the `unbind()` method on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unidirectional Bindings

The methods involved in unidirectional bindings are `bind`, `unbind`, and `isBound`.

It is important to know that unidirectional bindings are *one-to-one*<sup>1</sup>. This is done to maintain consistency. Consider what would happen if multiple unidirectional bindings were allowed at the same time. If we have:

`A` → `B`
`A` → `C`

What should `A` contain? The value of `B` or the value of `C`? The contract of `bind` requires that the `Property` will *always* contain the value of the `ObservableValue`. From `javafx.beans.property`:

> All properties can be bound to ObservableValues of the same type, which means that the property will always contain the same value as the bound ObservableValue.

The `Property` can't maintain this contract if there's more than one `ObservableValue` to observe. Thus, a one-to-one<sup>1</sup> relationship is enforced.

As a consequence of this one-to-one<sup>1</sup> relationship, it is not necessary to pass the `ObservableValue` when calling `unbind`. The only possible `ObservableValue` that could be meant is the one previously given via `bind`.

It's worth mentioning that calling `bind` on an already bound `Property` will implicitly unbind from the previous `ObservableValue`. At least, that's how the standard implementations work. I couldn't find documentation defining this behavior so I suppose an implementation could throw an exception instead.

<sup>1. Technically, it is a *many-to-one* relationship. More than one `Property` can be bound to the same `ObservableValue`, but that one `Property` cannot be bound to more than one `ObservableValue`. I'm leaving *one-to-one* in the answer, however, because I think it better illustrates the difference between unidirectional and bidirectional bindings.</sup>

### Bidirectional Bindings

The methods involved in bidirectional bindings are `bindBidrectional` and `unbindBidirectional`.

For bidirectional bindings, the relationship is *many-to-many*. They are also independent from unidirectional bindings. From `bindBidirectional`:

> Create a bidirectional binding between this Property and another one. Bidirectional bindings exists independently of unidirectional bindings. So it is possible to add unidirectional binding to a property with bidirectional binding and vice-versa. However, this practice is discouraged.
>
> It is possible to have multiple bidirectional bindings of one Property.

This many-to-many relationship is allowed for bidirectional bindings because they cause each `Property` to mirror *each other*. If one changes, the other updates.  From `javafx.beans.property`:

> It is also possible to define a bidirectional binding between two properties, so that both properties always contain the same value. If one of the properties changes, the other one will be updated.

This means the consistency issue that unidirectional bindings have isn't shared by bidirectional bindings. Consider the following:

`A` ↔ `B` ↔ `C`

If `A` changes, then `B` will update. Because `B` has updated, `C` will *also* update. This means at any given time all properties have the same value. No ambiguity.

As a consequence of this many-to-many relationship, the target `Property` *is* required when unbinding; the bound `Property` needs to know *which* `Property` it needs to unbind from.

Comment: Where did you find that `isBound` is for unidirectional? I can't find it in javadoc.

Comment: @Pavel_K I can't find documentation that states `isBound` is only for unidirectional bindings. However, I can say that all the standard implementations behave this way.

Comment: @Pavel_K By the way, technically the unidirectional bindings are _many-to-one_. More than one `Property` can be bound to the same `ObservableValue`, but that one `Property` can't be bound to more than one `ObservableValue`.

Comment: I agree with you.